# Equal height in all column using css with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am facing  a big problem in equal height columns  I have searched **SO** and i have found one solution. Apply the below css in the div (row) even after applying the below css it was no use when In the footer I have 5 Columns in the third column when I enter more data in the entire footer was getting increased but the first and second column was not increasing.

[image]

If you see the above image first two column and the last two  where not in the equal height

```
.equal, .equal > div[class*='col-'] {  
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex:1 0 auto;
}
```

**From the marked question  only i have take the equal class but it was equal only with first two column but not with other column :(**

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/nf7oo8c5/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: Hey buddy i have tried this question also but no help :(

Answer (score 0):

use your container with this css:

```css
#container{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
  background: skyblue;
}

#a {
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  background: gold;
}

#b {
  padding-right: 60px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  background: tomato;
}

#c {
  padding-right: 80px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  background: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
<div id=a>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br></div><div id=b>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br></div><div id=c>content<br>content<br>content<br></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean to say in the footer class or container

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox are the most modern solution, but you can do it also with display:table-cell, that works also in older browsers.

```css
.row{
  display: table;
}

.col{
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px
}

.col:nth-child(1){
  background: red;
}

.col:nth-child(2){
  background: yellow;
}

.col:nth-child(3){
  background: green;
}

.col:nth-child(4){
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Test<br>
    Test<br>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Test<br>
    Test<br>
    Test<br>
  
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Test<br>
    Test<br>
    Test<br>
    Test<br>
  </div>



</div>
```

Note: apply only on col-lg-* and col-md-* classes so on mobile should be responsive anyway.